# Can Shirkh be forgiven by if it is done unknowingly?

Tags: sharia, hadith

Childhood is the place where a person performs many sins knowingly or unknowingly.

A 14 year old kid doesn't know what is Shirkh and that it cannot be forgiven. So in this case will the kid's sins be forgiven as he is totally unaware to concept of Shirkh and is very young? Also can he ask for forgiveness after he is mature and understand what he is doing and that **Allah is the only one**?

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah.

Any sin that a person commits before reaching the age of puberty will not be held against them. Therefore, if a child commits sins before he becomes a mature young adult, he or she will not be held accountable for what they have done. It will be their responsibility however to learn the sins of Islam in order not to do them once they reach the age of puberty.

Answer (score 0):

As long as person is living their sin can be forgiven, even shirk as Allah (SWT) says in glorious Qur'an

> And those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves [by transgression], remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins - and who can forgive sins except Allah ? - and [who] do not persist in what they have done while they know. - [Qur'an 3:135](http://quran.com/3/135)

But if someone had died committing shirk his shirk will not be forgiven, any other sin Allah (SWT) may forgive, but shirk, no! as Allah (SWT) says in Qur'an

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin - [Qur'an 4:48](http://quran.com/4/48)

If person has sincerely asked for forgiveness, Allah (SWT) is all knowing all merciful.

and Allah (SWT) knows best